# GCP Memorystore host discovery and CNAME

Tags: google-cloud-platform

With AWS Elasticache, the connection host is returned as a CNAME (for example mycluster.1abc4d.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com)

I am using GCP App Engine With GCP Memorystore.

It looks like Memorystore Redis returns an IP to an instance, rather than a CNAME.

- Is this IP forever fixed? (What happens when clusters are added/removed?)
- Is there any way to discover this IP for this host?

Should we have any concerns with using the IP directly? Or is there any settings that I can turn on to get a CNAME back from GCP that points to the Redis instance?

Comment: Why does he need to discover the IP? Can you elaborate what exactly you mean by "Is there any way to discover this IP for this host" ?

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know [Memorystore for Redis supports two connection modes](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/networking), direct peering and private service access. Regardless of the connection mode, Memorystore for Redis always uses internal IP addresses to provision Redis instances.

- Is this IP forever fixed? (What happens when [clusters are added/removed](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting-cluster)?)
  Yes, there are no specific events that would cause the IP address of a running Redis instance to change except the deletion of the Instance
- Should we have any concerns with using the IP directly?
  You should not have any concerns using IP directly, however to improve your security and facilitate your IP management it is strongly suggested that you use [Private services access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#service-networking)
- Is there any settings that I can turn on to get a CNAME back from GCP that points to the Redis instance?
  Yes, you can [create a CNAME record](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_cname_record) using our service Cloud DNS to points to your Redis instance